# How Print single field multiple times as per Quantity on Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on crystal reports. I want to print same field multiple times as per Quantity.

if I enter Quantity 6 then it must print 6 times same filed..

How I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will explain you some steps just try it

1. Take a formula field
2. Use for loop in the formula area   in which
   append the text to same variable so it you will get a string with
   multiple times repeated
3. Place that formula field in your report
   and adjust the width to come to the next line
4. In properties window
   edit the CanGrow field and give max number of lines as per your
   requirement.

hope this will help you,

Comment: No mention pravin, if it helped you just accept the answer then others can use it,

Comment: @Gurunadh will u please show an example code of formula field.

Comment: @UmairAnwaar, Please go through this simple document http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-formula-field.htm ping me back if you still have any doubts on it, i will explain